# How do I share an entire bookmarks folder between two firefox sync users?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, firefox-sync, xmarks

I am trying to share a folder of bookmarks I use at work in firefox, so that this specific folder is available at home.

I am using Firefox Sync to synchronise among diferent instances of firefox in different computers and I am also using XMarks to share those bookmarks with Chrome.

This is the setup:

- Work computer: Firefox with `my.name@company.domain` profile both in firefox sync and xamrks. Folder `Work@company` is to be shared.
- Home computer: Firefox with `my.name@gmail.com` where the `Work@company` folder is meant to be shared

Xmarks only allows sharing of folders as webpages and Firefox Sync seems to be all or nothing from the options I have seen and tried.

Has anyone figured  out a way to share a bookmark folder with another computer?

Note that I am ok with unidirectional sync (Work -> Home) but I would prefer for it to be bidirectional.